# Using geopandas to plot integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am triying to make a Europe plot with Geopandas and data from Eurostat Api. I have created a column in my dataframe called 'trace' that is the one that I want to display but when I execute I got this traceback

```
/home/lasai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py:376: UserWarning: The GeoSeries you are attempting to plot is empty. Nothing has been displayed.
  UserWarning,

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-539cd0ac0c4b> in <module>
      6 crop.plot(column = 'trace',ax=ax, cmap='YlOrRd', legend = True,
      7           legend_kwds = {'shrink':0.55},
----> 8           missing_kwds={ "color": "lightgrey", "alpha": 0.2, "edgecolor": "grey", "hatch": "///"}
      9          )
     10 crop.boundary.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black')
```

If I use the other column called 'PC' it works great so I have no clue why it doesn't work. You can find the complete code on the Jupyter Notebook on the Map 1 section on this link [Eurostat Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/eurostat/statistics-coded/blob/codinglab/popul/living_conditions_poverty_social_exclusion/living_conditions_poverty_social_exclusion_py.ipynb)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you show the results of crop.info()?